# Finding records that don't share a relationship

Tags: mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL - find records from one table which don’t exist in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367863/sql-find-records-from-one-table-which-dont-exist-in-another)

I have the following (simplified) schema in MySQL:

[image: simplified schema]

An arrow indicates a one (non-arrow side) to many (arrow side) relationship.

I want to determine, for which delivery_zone_weeks, does a customer not have a weekly_order.

Comment: Can you include your DB schema?

Comment: Please also include few sample result set rows from the query you're hoping to create.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/544094/mysql-finding-rows-that-dont-take-part-in-a-relationship?rq=1. Both these are listed in the **Related** sidebar, how'd you miss them in your search?

Comment: Schema and sample data: http://pastebin.com/JmxWzM8N

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to understand fully without structures, sample data and expected result, but seems to be risking it a bit you need

```
SELECT * FROM DELIVERY_ZONE_WEEK WHERE ID_DELIVERY_ZONE_WEEK NOT IN
(SELECT WO.ID_DELIVERY_ZONE_WEEK FROM CUSTOMER C
JOIN SHIPPING_ADDRESS SA
    ON C.ID_CUSTOMER = SA.ID_CUSTOMER
JOIN WEEKLY_ORDER WO
    ON SA.ID_SHIPPING = WO.ID_SHIPPING
WHERE C.ID_CUSTOMER = @ID_CUSTOMER)
```