# Searching multiple rows that are not in a relationship n:m

Tags: mysql, sql

Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544094/mysql-finding-rows-that-dont-take-part-in-a-relationship)

Very similar to the question above but with a slight difference, I need to find a list of users that haven't seen at least one film in a list of movies.

Assuming two tables 'movies' and 'users', there's an n:m relationship between those, and a table 'seen' describing that relationship.

I need to find out for **any number of given users**, and **any number of given movies** all the **users**, from that given list, that have not watched **at least one** of the given movies.

Is this achievable in a single query? I can't figure out a way of do that.

Edit: Here's a demo with an attempt to solve the problem, the issue with that is it returns users that not have seen all of the movies from the given list. What we need is a user that has not seen ANY of the movies from that list: http://rextester.com/DEIH39789

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Your attempt at a query is also helpful.  Don't depend on another question for this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should give you your desired result. I'm assuming your basic structure is:

```
users (id int, name varchar(20));
movies (id int, title varchar(20));
seen (user_id int, movie_id int);

SELECT u.*
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN seen s
ON s.user_id = u.id AND s.movie_id IN (movielist)
WHERE s.user_id IS NULL AND u.id IN (userlist)
```

The `WHERE s.user_id IS NULL` condition means the `LEFT JOIN` gives you all the users who have not seen *any* of the movies in `movielist`, and the `u.id IN (userlist)` then restricts the results to only that set of users.
You would modify the `IN` clauses to match the list of movies and users you were interested in. I've made a small [demo on Rextester](http://rextester.com/DEIH39789).

**Update**

I had misinterpreted the question; the desired result is for users who have not seen one (or more) of the movies in the list. This query solves that problem:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM musers u
LEFT JOIN seen s
ON s.user_id = u.id AND s.movie_id IN (1, 2)
WHERE u.id IN (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY u.id
HAVING COUNT(s.movie_id) < 2
```

The result of the `JOIN` and `WHERE` is users (1, 2, 3) and the movies they have seen. If they have seen all of the movies in the movie list `(1, 2)`, the `COUNT` of movies in `seen` will be 2, otherwise, if they have not seen one (or more) it will be less than 2. Here's an [updated demo](http://rextester.com/EKCJ9985). Note that when the length of the movie list changes, the `2` in the `HAVING` clause must change to match the length of the movie list.

Comment: Thanks for that, I didn't know about the rextester, have put it in the question. This doesn't solve the problem because it returns users that have seen at least one of the movies in the list. if you change one of the lines to say user 3 watched movie 3, it should still return that user because it hasn't seen movies 1 and 2.

Comment: @caiocpricci2 Normally I use [SQLFiddle](www.sqlfiddle.com) for SQL as it has a nicer interface with text to DDL conversion but it's been a bit unreliable of late.

Comment: @caiocpricci2 please see my updated answer. The new query returns users who have not seen one (or more) of the movies in the list, not just those who haven't seen any of them.

Comment: Thanks for updating that, I understand now what i was doing wrong. Very good explanation, beautiful answer.

Comment: No worries. Thank you for your kind words.

Answer (score 0):

considering a n:m relationship between Users and Movies table, with intermediate table Seen.

```
SELECT * FROM Users u WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT UserId FROM Seen s WHERE s.UserId = u.ID)
```

this query will return Users which does not have any related record in Seen table

Comment: The question involves 'any number of given movies' not 'any movie'. I think that your code fails to take that into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

I would say something like a left-joining the users-table to the seen-table (and join that table to the movies-table).

(edited the code due to a comment from MatBailie)

Add the list-restritctions in the JOIN-clause (and not the WHERE-clause as MatBailie pointed out to me) and you get something like (Code below should work on SQL-Server but something similar should work for MySql as well):

```
SELECT COUNT(Users.ID)
FROM Users
LEFT JOIN Seen ON Users.ID = Seen.UserID AND Users.something IN (list)
LEFT JOIN Movies ON Seen.MovieID = Movie.ID AND Movies.something IN (list)
WHERE Movies.ID IS NULL
GROUP BY User.ID -- <-- This is probably optional
```

But as there are usually multiple ways to get the same result, the adjusted version of my previous answer:

```
SELECT COUNT(Users.ID)
FROM Users
LEFT JOIN Seen ON Users.ID = Seen.UserID
LEFT JOIN Movies ON Seen.MovieID = Movie.ID
WHERE (Users.something IN (list) OR Users.something IS NULL)
  AND (Movies.something IN (list) OR Movies.something IS NULL)
  AND Movies.ID IS NULL
GROUP BY User.ID -- <-- This is probably optional
```

Third attempt: Get all user-ids in list that have seen one of the movies. Next, get all user-ids in list and subtract the user-ids that have seen one of these movies. Know that for large data sets (a couple of thousand is not large) this query might become slow. To test it I've removed "userid = 2 and movieid = 3" from the list of seen, else I would not get a result. Now I see that Nick has not seen any of the first three movies (referring to your rextester example)

```
SELECT *
FROM musers
WHERE musers.id IN (1,2,3)
  AND musers.id NOT IN (
    SELECT musers.id
    FROM musers
    JOIN Seen ON musers.ID = Seen.UserID 
    JOIN Movies ON Seen.MovieID = movies.ID 
    WHERE movies.id IN (1,2,3) )
```

Comment: `Users.something IN (list)` and `Movies.something IN (list)` need to move out of the `WHERE` and in to the `LEFT JOIN`s, otherwise you're turning them back into `INNER JOIN`s.

Comment: Darn, I overlooked that. Although in all fairness, there are two ways to fix that. But I admit that adding the conditions in the join-clause feels more natural.

Comment: I am confused, this seems like it should work but it's not. I put this solution into the rexter provided by @Nick in the next reply (big thanks, didn't know this tool). http://rextester.com/BKWOC34536 the results are confusing. I expected user 3 to have a count of 1 and user 6 to have a count of 2 for example. Maybe i'm just interpreting this wrong?

Comment: I've added a third attempt to the answer. This appear to work.